# AngularJS $http success callback data return

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service, angular-http

Hello everyone :) Here is the problem. I'm making an angular app with:

- a factory to access to an api with $http that retrieves an array of objects from a server

  ```
  getObjectsFromApi : function(){
      return $http({
          url: 'http://path/to/the/api/',
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8',
          }
      })       
  },
  ```
- and a service to compute retrieved data and inject it to controllers

  ```
  this.getObjectsFromService = function(){
      var objects = [];

      ObjectFactory.getObject()
      .success(function(data, status){
          console.log("Successfully got objects !");
          objects = data;
      })
      .error(function(data, status){
          console.log("Fail... :-(");
      });

      return objects;
  };
  ```

The problem is that when I return objects, it doesn't return any data. How can I do to return $http callback data within this getObjectsFromService function ?

Thank you for helping !

Answer (score 1):

You must use promises, something like this should do the trick

```
this.getObjectsFromService = function(){
    var defer = $q.defer();

    ObjectFactory.getObject()
    .then(function(data){
        console.log("Successfully got objects !");
        defer.resolve(data);
    })
    .catch(function(data){
        console.log("Fail... :-(");
         defer.reject(data);
    });

    return defer.promise;
};
```

And now you can use this function somewhere else like this:

```
var foo = function() {
    var objects = [];
    this.getObjectsFromService().then(function(data) {
        objects = data;
        //do rest of your manipulation of objects array here
    });
}
```

There is no other way to return the objects, it's not possible because $http is asynchronous. You'll have to rework the rest of the code and adapt it to this

Answer (score 0):

```
var req = ObjectFactory.getObject();

req.success(function(data) {...}
req.error(function(data) {...}
```

This will do it for ya

The variable req will then be the promise sent back from the factory.

**Edit**

Keep in mind that your data will not be changes until the promise is resolved, so if you try to console.log(objects) before then, it will be empty.

Comment: I missed on my explanations: The problem is that I want to return data I got from the api in order to inject it in the controller.  In other words, I want to get response data, put it into my "objects" variable and return this variable. So sorry for the bad english ... :-/

Comment: This will solve that issue as well. Replace your code where the '...' is.

Answer (score 0):

The http request is async, which means that it completes *after* you return `objects`. Return the promise instead:

```
this.getObjectsFromService = function(){
    return ObjectFactory.getObject().catch(function(){
        console.log("Fail... :-(");
    });
}
```

Then

```
service.getObjectsFromService().then(function(resp) {
    console.log("Successfully got objects !", resp.data);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code is asynchronous. When you return objects, you return your initial empty array. You can't return directly your object, but instead you need to return a promise (see 3 possibilities below)

By creating a promise

```
var deferred = $q.defer();

ObjectFactory.getObjectsFromApi()
    .success(function(data, status){
        console.log("Successfully got objects !");
        // Do stuff and resolve promise
        deferred.resolve(data);
     })
     .error(function(data, status){
         console.log("Fail... :-("));
         // Do stuff and reject promise
         deferred.reject(data)
     });

return deferred.promise;
```

You can use promise chaining (use .then rather than .success and .error):
*Note: when using then with success and error callbacks rather than success and error methods, you have only 1 argument which is the response object*

```
return  ObjectFactory.getObjectsFromApi()
    .then(function(response){
        console.log("Successfully got objects !");
        // Do stuff and chain full response headers or data
        return responseHeaders;
        // or
        // return responseHeaders.data;
     }, function(responseHeaders){
         console.log("Fail... :-("));
         // Do stuff and chain error (full response headers or data)
         return $q.reject(responseHeaders)
         // return $q.reject(responseHeaders.data);
     });
```

Or if you have no business logic, or no reason to intervene in your factory, simply return your $http call directly:

```
return  ObjectFactory.getObjectsFromApi();
```

Comment: You have way too many returns in your code. This will not work.

Comment: Yes, I had one return that I accidentally left, on the first example. The rest is correct. If you think there are too many returns, look at asynchronous programming ad promise chaining.

Answer (score -2):

## Angular $resource

### Factory

```
getObjectsFromApi : function(){
    return $resource('http://path/to/the/api/', {}, 
    {
        get: {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'
            } 
        }
    })       
},
```

### Service

```
this.getObjectsFromService = function(){
    var objects = [];

    ObjectFactory.get().$promise.then(function(data) {
         objects = data;
         return objects;
    }).error(function(err) {
        throw err;
    });
};
```

Comment: This will return an empty array, the call to ObjectFactory is async.